# Prepare default new line as replacement of empty values

Tags: c#, linq

I'm working on reporting using rdlc where the report footer position needs to stay at bottom, but the four table footer visibility depend on certain condition.

For that I use `Union` and use `Take(4)` to make sure if any of the table footer is not visible it should be replaced with `\r\n` at the bottom.

Should be:

```
12345
\r\n
\r\n
\r\n
```

Not like this:

```
\r\n
\r\n
\r\n
12345
```

Here is my code.

```
var footerValues = new[]
{
    salesOrder.Subtotal.ToString("N0"),
    salesOrder.Discount.ToString("N0"),
    salesOrder.PPN.ToString("N0"),
    salesOrder.Total.ToString("N0")
};
var stats = new[] { 
    salesOrder.Discount >= 1 || salesOrder.PPN >= 1, // combined visibility
    salesOrder.Discount >= 1,  // visible only if the value >= 1
    salesOrder.PPN >= 1, // visible only if the value >= 1
    true // total always visible
};
var textValues = stats
    .Select((v, i) => v ? footerValues[i] : null).OfType<string>()
    .Union(Enumerable.Range(0, 4).Select(x => string.Empty).ToArray())
    .Take(4)
    .ToArray()
var footerValue = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, textValues);
```

If the stats produces

```
false, false, false, true
```

The expected `footerValue` would be

```
"12345\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n"
```

But actual result is

```
"12345\r\n"
```

What's wrong with the code? Or can it be simplified?

Comment: `.Union(Enumerable.Range(0, 4).Select(x => string.Empty).ToArray())` is pointless. it will only return one string.Empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This part:

```
.Union(Enumerable.Range(0, 4).Select(x => string.Empty).ToArray())
```

is pointless. it will only return one `string.Empty`. Because `Union` removes the duplicates. I think you want `Concat` instead.Btw, you can also replace `Enumerable.Range` with `Enumerable.Repeat`

```
var textValues = stats
.Select((v, i) => v ? footerValues[i] : null).OfType<string>()
.Concat(Enumerable.Repeat(string.Empty, 4))
.Take(4)
.ToArray();
```

Comment: that works like a magic, thanks, the `Repeat` part also make the code simpler, much appreciate